# Writing Into a file using Java

Tags: java, file-io

```
 public static void writeIntoFile() {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = null;
        try {
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("Employee.txt");
            objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(list1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fileOutputStream == null) {
                System.out.println("file is not created");
            }
            if (objectOutputStream == null) {
                System.out.println("cant able to write");
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to using this function to writing in a file. it writes successfully but it display data in bytecode. how can I save it into string format?

Comment: You have a few choices.  You make it so that you can write the properties in the format you want.  That's a lot of work and is really messy or you could use [Java Architecture for XML Binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/) that will allow you to read/write object properties in the form of XML

Answer (score 3):

Use a `FileWriter` wrapped inside a `BufferedWriter` to write character data to a `File`.

`ObjectOutputStream` is used for serialization and results in a binary encoded file. Its only useful if you only want to load the file through your program and do not wish to read its contents elsewhere like in an external editor.

You also need to iterate through your `List` and save the requisite properties of your underlying `Object` in a format you wish to parse your `File` later on in. For example, as CSV (comma separated values) every `Employee` object and its properties would be persisted as one single line in the output file.

```
BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Employee.csv"));
for (Employee employee : list) {
    br.write(employee.getFName() + ", " + employee.getLName());
    br.newLine();
}
br.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

in the function writeIntoFile  is write a Serialization Object into file

you should use  the object's toString() to write a String into file

Answer (score 0):

you can change bytecode into string using one simple way.
pass the bytecode into string constructor
like this:

new String(bytecode object);

and then write string object into file.

Comment: If you can provide a runnable example of writing and reading the object, I'll give you an up-vote

Comment: FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
         ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
         // write something in the file
         oout.writeObject("Hello World");
         oout.writeObject(new Integer(897648764);); // this statement write byte code 
         oout.writeObject(String.valueOf(new Integer(897648764);.intValue()));   //this statement write integer value
         // close the stream
         oout.close();

Comment: So you're not so much writing the `Object` as `String`, but properties of the `Object`??

Comment: for properties of the object use object serialization.